# Good family relationship

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language

Mr.K's message:

> It's a beautiful day outside! Geese are flying.
>
> Remember that my favorite seafood is squid?
>
> It's best served with Java waterdropwort!
>
> Let's eat them next time we meet, dad.
>
> Also note that, when I drink water, I always use a bowl made of a gourd.
>
> It's such an antiquated fashion to do in Seoul!
>
> Meanwhile, it's nice to hear the chime of my house – a silver bell.
>
> For you, maybe I should buy more bowls made of gourds?
>
> Also I remember going to Naples when I was young.
>
> I asked people there whether they know Yi **[REDACTED]**! Haha, silly times.
>
> To think about it, I think the squid would also go well together with platycodon.
>
> Now try to decrypt this message, dad!

Comment: The author of the message is dead, with silver bells on the tombstone, and mourners bring gourd bowls of holy water to the grave.